# Property with no iVar and getter method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I spotted this today and just want to verify my understanding of what is going on. "prefixName" is a readonly property that uses a getter method to directly pass a value back, there is no iVar storing the result on the PR_ViewController object. Also if the property was not readonly adding a setter still would not work as there is no iVar to set.

- Created: [Meth] prefixName

By contrast "characterName" works the usual way for a property, adding a getter, a setter and an iVar.

- Created: [Meth] characterName
- Created: [Meth] setCharacterName
- Created: [iVar] characterName

.

```
@interface PR_ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *prefixName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *characterName;
```

.

```
@implementation PR_ViewController
@synthesize characterName;

- (NSString *)prefixName {
    return @"FRED";
}
```

Comment: Don't duplicate your questions. Please close one of this.

Comment: You're understanding it correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Property with no iVar and getter method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788773/property-with-no-ivar-and-getter-method)

Comment: very strange, I am not sure what happened there as I did not post this question twice. Apologies for any confusion ...

Comment: I actually can't see a duplicate here, the link to the duplicate above points back to this question. That is unless the duplicate has already been removed.

Comment: Very strange, I defiantly only posted once and my actions/activity log for the site only show one post (this one) this year. So not sure what happened to be truthful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not required to synthesize accessors - you can perfectly well write them yourself, which is what is done in your example.

Further, a read-only property does not have to be based on an ivar, but can be computed, based on other ivars or properties. This can be useful if you use bindings to display values in the UI that are derived from other properties, provided you like that coding style.

Here is a simple example of a readonly property computed based on two other properties:

Header file:

```
@property double width;
@property double height;

@property (readonly) double area;
```

Implementation:

```
@synthesize width, height;

- (double)area
{
    return width*height;
}


+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingArea
{
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"width", @"height", nil];
}
```

Now, whenever either one of `width` or `height` changes, the `area` property changes, too, and its changes are propagated to its listeners (thanks to `keyPathsForValuesAffectingArea`.)

You can also see the `fullName` example in this [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html).

Comment: I understand that you can write getter and setters manually, but was more asking about not having an iVar backing the property. In the example above prefixName does not have an iVar on the object, characterName does.

Comment: I guess we understand each other, but I think of it as the ivar being just one of many ways to store or compute the value of the property. It could also be the sum of an array of numbers, for instance.

Comment: Thank you, I think I might understand it now. In a situation where you don't add an iVar manually or use @synthesis to generate one you add the accessors (getter & setter) manually. However there is no value for the getter to return so you have to compute one in the method, like wise with the setter there is nothing to set so the setter is a bit redundant (unless of course you want to be a bit convoluted and set something else/some other iVar.